# How can we forward a port to QEMU which has a server on the port already running?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, portforwarding

I have a Python server running at port `28009`:

```
python3 -m http.server 28009
```

Now, after I run the server I call QEMU to forward port `28009`:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt,gic-version=max -m 512M -cpu max -smp 4 \
-netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=tcp::28009-:28009 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet \
-drive file=ubuntu-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 \
-drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash
```

It produces an error saying:

```
qemu-system-aarch64: Could not set up host forwarding rule 'tcp::28009-:28009'
```

Similarly, if I run the above QEMU script first it boots alright. However, the Python server now throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 1211, in <module>
    test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 1185, in test
    with ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) as httpd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

How can I have the server running and enable QEMU to access this server? I cannot use a [TUN](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking#TAP_interfaces) connection as I need to have localhost of the host machine talking to QEMU and vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hostfwd option is for forwarding connections from the outside world to a server which is running on the *guest*. "hostfwd=tcp::HOSTPORT-:GUESTPORT" says "QEMU should listen on the host on port HOSTPORT; whenever a connection arrives there, it should forward it to the guest's port GUESTPORT (which hopefully has a server listening there)".

You seem to be running a server on the *host*. You can't have more than one thing listening on a particular port on one machine, so either the python3 server program can listen on port 28009 and respond to connections there, or QEMU can listen on port 28009 to respond to connections there (forwarding them to the guest), but not both at once. Whichever is started second will complain that something's already using the port.

If you want to run a server on the host and connect to it from the guest, you don't need any QEMU options at all. QEMU's 'usermode' networking will allow guest programs to make connections outwards to any IP address (including the wider internet but also directly to the host), so if you are trying to run a client on the guest and a server on the host that should just work. You can tell the guest client to connect either to the host's real IP address or you can use the special 'gateway' IP address 10.0.2.2 which is how the host machine appears on the fake network that the guest sees.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for clarifying Peter. Should have gone through the complete documentation description of `hostfwd`. If you do get the time could you have a look at a similar (if not related) [question asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520919/how-can-i-share-the-localhost-of-my-host-computer-with-a-qemu-image)

Comment: @Peter You answer a lot of off topic questions about networking and QEMU for example. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Vote to close them instead.

Comment: This is where people are asking questions, so this is where I answer them. If you want to move them elsewhere and there's a mechanism for that, feel free.

Comment: They are being closed and deleted, not moved. Again, as the rule I linked to states: "Do not answer off topic questions."

Comment: I think that's being actively unhelpful to people who would like help, and to people in the future who might have similar questions. Please don't do that.