# How to connect a Server in linux (host) with a client running in QEmu's guest linux (guest)

Tags: networking, server, arm, client, qemu

I want to connect via TCP socket a **server** app running in the host with a client running in the QEmu guest.
I use port **5104** for the socket in the **server**.
I start the **server**.

Then I found that I can not launch the QEmu giving that port as the input point for the client in the guest, like this:

```
qemu-system-arm ... -net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:5104-:5104
```

Gives the error "Could not setup host forwarding rule ..."

I guess that qemu acts like a server also and then the port is already taken by the server previously launched and then is not possible to do it.

Which is the correct syntax? The documentation talks about the option **guestfwd** but I tried all the possibilities and I couldn't found the solution. It should be way to do it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518330/how-can-we-forward-a-port-to-qemu-which-has-a-server-on-the-port-already-running/67520103#67520103 which answers your question (you do not need to use any QEMU options at all, neither hostfwd nor guestfwd, to allow a client inside QEMU to connect to a server on the host)

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. 
I don't define any network configuration in qemu and from the guest I connect to 10.0.2.2 port 5104 and that's all.